# Flood fill using recursion - Python

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, backtracking, flood-fill

I have to solve the known problem of flood fill recursively not using any module.

> My function has to recieve a matrix of "image" which contains ' * ' and '.', and a tuple that indicates the origin by row and column. We can assume that the frame of the image is filled with only ' * ' and the start point element equals to '.'. The function has to change from the start all the '.' by '*' with the rules of moving in flood fill.

So I have written a code which is supposed to solve that, but the function exceeding the maximum recursion depth...

I have been looking for the problem like 2 hours and nothing.

Here is my code:

```
def f_f(image, start):
    i, j = start[0], start[1]
    f_f_helper(image, i, j)


def f_f_helper(image, i, j):
    if image[i][j] == '.':
        image[i][j] = '*'

    if i > 0:
        f_f_helper(image, i - 1, j)
    if i < len(image) - 1:
        f_f_helper(image, i + 1, j)
    if j > 0:
        f_f_helper(image, i, j - 1)
    if j < len(image[0]) - 1:
        f_f_helper(image, i, j + 1)
```

And one more thing, how do I calculate the running time formally with big O notation?

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that you end up re-visiting cells you've already seen. You'll want to keep track of them somehow.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't visit cells that are already the "color" you want to fill with.

Comment: That's the proof that I can't imagine what's going on with recursive problems... But even if I revisit the cells I have already seen - it has to terminate eventually, no? As for the second problem, before every recursive call - I have to check if the tuple I want to send is already filled?

Comment: I didn't succeed to overcome these problems...